# Usernames of some users are long with characters

Tags: 2010, user-accounts

Usernames of some of the users is showing in following format.

> i:0#.f|aspnetsqlmembershipprovider|username

Is it possible to solve it?

Strangely 80%-85% usernames do not face this issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to add here that I have read that a Cumulative Update solves this issue but don't know which!

Answer (score 1):

Check that the users have first and last name defined in SharePoint User Profile database - and in your case in the ASP.NET user database.